# NodeJS get SubjectPublicKeyInfo

Tags: node.js, go, ssl

I try to convert this Go code into NodeJS. The Go code downloads the tls cert for a given host and creates a hash for the subject pulic key info.

```
func Fingerprint(c *x509.Certificate) string {
    digest := sha256.Sum256(c.RawSubjectPublicKeyInfo)
    return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(digest[:])
}

func fromServer(server string) error {
    conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", server, &tls.Config{
        InsecureSkipVerify: true,
    })

    if err != nil {return err}

    for _, cert := range conn.ConnectionState().PeerCertificates {
        fmt.Println(Fingerprint(cert))
    }

    return nil
}
```

[Full Code](https://github.com/tam7t/hpkp/blob/master/cmd/hpkp-pins/main.go)

I came up with this code

```
function fingerprint(cert) {
    const digest = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(cert).digest();
    return Buffer.from(digest).toString('base64');
}

function fromServer(server) {
    const socket = tls.connect({ host: server.split(':')[0], port: server.split(':')[1], rejectUnauthorized: false }, () => {
        const cert = socket.getPeerCertificate();
        // console.log(fingerprint(cert.??))
        
        socket.end();
    });
}
```

My problem is that i cant find the value the is used for the fingerprint. In Go i logged the`RawSubjectPublicKeyInfo` with `fmt.Println(hex.EncodeToString(c.RawSubjectPublicKeyInfo))` and the value is part of the NodeJS `cert.raw.toString('hex')` but i didn't found it "standalone" or a way to convert the raw cert.

Answer (score 2):

[The doc](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/tls.html#certificate-object) isn't specific, but `.pubkey` is a `Buffer` containing (DER-encoded) SPKI, which is what you want. At least since the version in dockerhub's node:10-alpine; 8 or lower doesn't seem to have it.